# Is it possible to allow only photo taking and not photo upload on an input file type?

Tags: html, css, file, input, mobile

I have a web application where users on mobile can take pictures with an input type file.
I would like to disallow those users to upload their files but only allow them to take picture from there camera.

Is it possible ?
If not is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <input type="file" id="capture-image" accept="image/*"capture="camera">

This will do the trick.

Comment: will work on mobile only. but if user open the web app using desktop browser, the browser will open file upload window.